# System.OutOfMemoryException occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll

Tags: azure-storage

While retrieving data from Azure Table Storage, I'm recieving this error. Has any1 received this kind of error before

An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll but was not handled in user code

-Mahender

Answer (score 0):

Found reasons for Out of Memory issue, this is because of getting too much of collection data from Azure table storage client. Resolved by pulling only required columns from table in select statement of lINQ query.